# Excepcion PHP-SQL preparándola

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando capturar la excepción que da cuando se inserta una PK duplicada en el PHP pero no funciona.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->tableUsers . " (Dni,Name,Surname,E_mail,Rol,Passw) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->conexion, $query);

        $rol = 'admin';
        $password = sha1('123');

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $dni, $name, $surname, $email, $rol, $password);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        unset($stmt);
        if (mysqli_error($this->conexion)) {
           header('Location:Error.php?message=duplicada' ); 
        }
```

He visto gente que lo que hace es una select y con un $row > 0 es que ya existe, PERO YO NO QUIERO ESO, no quiero tener que lanzar una consulta para saber si está y sino está insertar, es doble trasiego de información .....

Quiero poder capturar la excepción del duplicate primary key que lanza el Mysql en PHP. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ejecución por procedimientos de `mysqli_stmt_execute` devuelve un booleano. Por tanto debiera ser:

```
$ejecucion = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if(!$ejecucion) {
  header('Location:Error.php?message='.mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) ); 
}
```